# Visual-Studio 2013 changes my wstring

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, wstring

I have the following code:

```
bool IsCharVowel(const wstring uChar)
{
    if (Has(L"aeiouäöüúéáàèùò",uChar))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool Has(wstring uSearchIn, wstring uSearchFor)
{

    if (uSearchFor.size()==0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (uSearchIn.find(uSearchFor)!=wstring::npos)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

As soon as I inspect the passed wstring in the function "Has", the wstring is different from what I have entered:

uSearchIn = L"aeiouÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃºÃ©Ã¡Ã Ã¨Ã¹Ã²"

Does anybody see what is going wrong here?

Comment: Looks like a character encoding mismatch.

Comment: @Philipp Can you explain that?

Comment: Somewhere the string gets interpreted in the wrong character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!

I changed the encoding of the .cpp file to "UTF-8 (no signature)"

I have now switched it to "UTF-8 (with signature)".

Now it works as expected.

Comment: You probably could have done it also with some option somewhere. I do wish Windows would get with the times and start using UTF-8 by default.